# How do I properly concatenate in python with my program

Tags: python, concatenation

I am currently learning Python and am trying to understand what is wrong with my code:
(The point of this program is to find out the input of a number given and determine if it is above 50 to print big or is it is below 50, to print small.

```
x =  int(input('Enter your number:'))
if x >= 50:
    print(x+''+'is big')
else:
    print(x+''+ 'is small')
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are having trouble with?

Comment: Yes, you can't use `+` to *add* together an `int` and a `str`.

Comment: What does `"counts as an interger"` mean? Well, no, using an `f-string` just converts everything to a string and concatenates everything together as the format describes.

Comment: so in this case, could have I avoided this by never using making the 1st line an interger?

Comment: No, you need to do the `int(input ...` so that the next line: `x >= 50` works. (Alternatively you could have kept `x` as a `str` and done: `int(x) >= 50:`)

Answer (score 0):

X is Integer value and you will get TypeError Exception because we couldn't concatenate Integer value with string.

In Concatenation you can use:

- print("{} is big".format(x))
- print(f"{x} is big")

Answer (score 0):

You can either use f-strings just as @mozway said and you can also just use a comma like `print(x, "is small)`/`print(x, "is big")`

Comment: If you do the latter, be aware of what the `sep` argument to `print` is.